# heroku connect to mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, django, heroku

I have push a python-django project to heroku and it works well. In my view.py file  of django model, I added function that could connect to the local mysql database to retrieve data from the mysql. The function is the view.py is as followed:

```
@login_required 
def results(request):
    data=[]
    data1 = []
    owner = request.user
    owner = str(owner)
    db = MySQLdb.connect(user='root', db='aaa', passwd='xxxxx', host='localhost')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT search_content, id, title, author, institute, FROM result_split where username = '%s'" % (owner))
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    db.close()
    return render(request, "webdevelop/results.html", {"datas": data})
```

But when I try to open the page that show the data from mysql database in the deployed heroku website, it show the error:"OperationalError at /results/
(2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")". How could I have this heroku project to connect to my local mysql database? Or I should choose alternative?

Comment: There are quite a few things wrong here. How are you expecting to connect to mysql on localhost? Heroku won't run a database on the same server as your app. Buy why are you correcting explicitly to a db anyway rather than using the models API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to ensure that the user and password you're using to connect to MySQL is correct and that the user has the correct privileges to work with the selected database.
Then you can check that mysql is accepting connections on localhost.

As for directly addressing the Connection Refused exception, check things like the mysql socket used to communicate with localhost applications like your Django project. The socket must exist and be configured in MySQL.

I also recommend taking a look at something like SQLAlchemy for Python which will help you interact directly with the database using Python objects. For example,

Connecting to the database:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship, scoped_session, mapper
from config import DB_URL


"""Database Declaration"""

metadata = MetaData()
Base = declarative_base(name='Base', mapper=mapper, metadata=metadata)

engine = create_engine(DB_URL, pool_recycle=1800)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine, autocommit=False, autoflush=True)
session = scoped_session(Session)
```

You can now use `session` variable to perform queries and updates using its inherited functions from the SQLAlchemy Session class.

SQLAlchemy also includes a declarative model for telling Python what your tables look like. For example,

```
class Clinic(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'clinic'

    clinic_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    clinic_name = Column(VARCHAR)
    address = Column(VARCHAR)
    city = Column(VARCHAR)
    zip = Column(VARCHAR)
    phone = Column(VARCHAR)
    user_id = Column(VARCHAR)
```

These examples work well for my projects in Flask and should work well enough in Django.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you be more specific about the "mysql socket used to communicate with localhost applications like your Django project"? How could I check socket must exist and be configured in MySQL? Sorry that I'm quite freshman in this area.

Comment: OP mentions they are using Django, so all this stuff about sqlalchemy is irrelevant. And you also failed to notice the mention of Heroku, which won't be running a db on localhost.

Comment: Thanks. So how could I apply the mysql database? In addition, the django project have one function to use the local python file. How could I import the file in heroku?

Comment: The reason I included SQLAlchemy is because some say Django's ORM isn't suited for complex database ops. It was just a suggestion from my experience.

Comment: Can you kindly suggest anyway to connect to my local mysql database or any other alternative?